# Am I interested in a Math-Fin PhD for the right reasons?

Tags: phd, mathematics

For the last few months I have been deliberating whether or not to apply to Masters and/or PhD programs in and related to Mathematical Finance. I am currently wrapping up a Mathematics Bachelors at my University, and have already received an offer to work as a Quantitative Analyst at a top 10 bank upon successful graduation. I very much loved the work I did there, and absolutely can see myself doing this type of work for a long period of time. However I have also been strongly considering graduate study in Mathematical Finance.

Some of my reasons for wanting to do a Mathematical Finance PhD are the following:

1. I love the work I did, and I love doing research in Quantitative Finance. The rest of my reasons are financial and career trajectory related.
2. The best offers in industry for Quants are usually off limits to anyone without an advanced degree in a Quantitative Discipline. Getting a Masters or PhD would significantly improve my long run earnings potential.
3. The more interesting roles (for me at least), namely those related to Capital Markets, are highly competitive even to those with strong degrees and work experience. Having a PhD could help me stand out from an already exceptionally talented crowd.
4. I have a significant amount of student loan debt from my undergraduate studies. If I go for a PhD, I can keep that debt deferred and invest any unused amount from departmental support and a part time job allowing me to grow my assets.

Some reasons why I am still unsure:

1. Although I have been already doing research in this area for years on my own, and I loved my internship experience, I am well aware doing a PhD is a whole different ballpark. Its a potential 6 year commitment, and not being able to remain committed for 6 years could screw me.
2. Since a lot of my concern is financial, is this really the best financial decision? It's not unreasonable that I could receive multiple pay increases after starting my job and bonuses that by far compensate me for not going to grad school right away.... In such case, I may not be better off for keeping my loans differed and investing the money I make.
3. Quality of Life: With my job, I get weekends, and depending on the needs of the business, evenings as well. With a PhD I am well aware that means potentially a 60 hour commitment. If I work part time for extra money, that means essentially no life outside of work. **To be honest, for the majority of my undergraduate studies, I have had almost no life. Only Study and Work. I don't know if I can do that anymore. Honestly I am quite sick of it!**

My current plan is the following: Apply to a select subset of highly competitive programs with good industry connections and or placements. If I can get into one of these programs, great! Otherwise, continue onward with my job, and perhaps a few years down the road pursue an MBA. Considering what I mentioned above, is this plan advisable, or perhaps should I consider a different route? Are the any other PROS/CONS that I have not considered? There are also other types of programs that are similar in trajectory e.g. Computational Finance, Financial Engineering. If I do go for a PhD, should I instead pursue one of those programs instead? I'd love to hear from anyone who has been in a similar situation!

Comment: There's a third option.  Work for a year or so in the field and then go to grad school.  You don't have to pay back your loan for the first six months, and after that, if you have some financial hardship, you can request a modified repayment schedule.  // If you're really lucky you'll get your employer to pay tuition for one or two courses per semester.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE Academia. Your post seems highly opinion-based and is thus likely to be closed. Can you make it more objective by focusing on a specific direct question?